# Auto-created EC2 instance and how to delete(terminate) it?

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm launching an EC2 instance in AWS. And there is an auto-created EC2 instance, named Test-env. Every time I terminated it, AWS would auto-created a new one for me. is there any way to terminate the auto-created instance and prevent it from creating a new one?

[image]

Shown in the picture above, I terminated the **Test-env** twice, and AWS just created a new **Test-env** for me.

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you have been using Elastic Beanstalk. If you open up that section of the AWS Management Console, you can delete the application/environment from there. This will bring down the instance as well. When you terminate the Elastic Beanstalk instance manually through the EC2 section, the system thinks that it has failed and will launch a replacement.

Reference: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=115913

Answer (score 1):

Other than Elastic Beanstalk and AutoScaling group,
another possibility is you have
an on-going Spot Request.

You can cancel it in order to prevent the instance from recreating.
`EC2 -> Instances -> Spot Requests`
Then, `Actions -> Cancel Request`

Comment: Finally, this was my issue. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

It seems that AutoScaling group configuration is present for the EC2 instance Test-env.
Can you please check under `EC2 -> AutoScaling Groups -> Test-env -> Scaling Policies`?

It seems that **ScaleUp Policy** has been configured for that instance. It means that whenever total number of EC2 instances are less than or equal to 0 (or any limit which was set) then spawn new one.

You need to update these policies or remove it as per your need.